# Sum of bst tree nodes with in certain range

Tags: algorithm, variables, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
var rangeSumBST = function(root, low, high) {
    let sum=0;

    if(root){
        sum+=(root.val>=low&&root.val<=high)?root.val:0;
        sum+=rangeSumBST(root.left,low,high);
        sum+=rangeSumBST(root.right,low,high);
    }
    
    return sum;
};
```

This is the function to find sum of values between certain range.

My doubt here is if we give sum =0 everytime it won't be initialized to zero.

Can anyone help me in understanding recursion concept here.

Can anyone provide link for recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is fine, but it is a pity that it visits *every* node of the tree. You can use `if` conditions to guard recursive calls which are sure to return 0, because their range (according to the BST property) is guaranteed to be outside the low/high range given to the function:

```js
var rangeSumBST = function(root, low, high) {
    if (!root) return 0;
    let sum = root.val >= low && root.val <= high ? root.val : 0;
    if (root.val >= low ) sum += rangeSumBST(root.left,  low, high);
    if (root.val <= high) sum += rangeSumBST(root.right, low, high);
    return sum;
};
```

If it is known that the BST will not have duplicate values, the `if` conditions can drop the equality condition... so `root.val > low` and `root.val < high`.

> My doubt here is if we give sum =0 everytime it won't be initialized to zero.

There is no problem there. Be aware that every call of `rangeSumBST` creates an execution context that has its own local variables. So for example, `let sum = 0` will only affect that local variable, and not the variables with the same name that live in other execution contexts of the same function.

Each call is *responsible* for the tree that it is given the root of, and will return the value of its `sum` variable to the caller, after which that execution context disappears -- including that `sum` variable. Then the caller trusts that this result is correct for its child tree, and accumulates it into its own `sum`.